# java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission

Tags: java, android

I am trying to perform an ENTER event in another application via Android's Accessibility Service, but it throws me this exception

> java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
>                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
>                                                                                   at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub$Proxy.injectInputEvent(IInputManager.java:417)
>                                                                                   at android.hardware.input.InputManager.injectInputEvent(InputManager.java:685)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.sendKeySync(Instrumentation.java:904)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(Instrumentation.java:914)

Is there a way around this? I basically want to perform ENTER event on run time from my application in another application.

Comment: The way around this is to aquire app permission that your security error talks about.

Comment: You may have better luck if you provide a [mcve], showing the code that generates this stack trace.

Comment: actually my app is tv box app and i open stan app within my tv box app using Accessibility Service. i want perform run time Enter Event on search box in stan

Comment: and how i make my application as system app